# How to overcome TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in this program

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am trying to calculate averages for a frequency table.

Now until the mean is printed everything works fine, but then after that I keep getting  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

until here the program is fine:

```
    import threading
    import statistics
    from statistics import mode
    import numpy as np
    print("Instructions:Enter a number than press ENTER until when fully completed")
    ScoresNumber=[]
    n = int(input("Entering amount of scores you want : "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
      
        ScoresNumber.append(ele) 
          
    print("These are the scores for the Frequency table",ScoresNumber)
    print("\n")

    print("Now enter Frequency")
    FrequencyNumber=[]
    a = int(input("Entering amount of frequencies you want : "))
    for i in range(0, a):
        ele = int(input())
      
        FrequencyNumber.append(ele)
    print("These are the frequencies for the Frequency table",FrequencyNumber)
    SumFrequencyNumber=sum(FrequencyNumber)
    print("Sum of elements in frequency is :",SumFrequencyNumber)
    print("\n")

    print ("Now calculating FX wait....")
    FX=[a * b for a, b in zip(FrequencyNumber,ScoresNumber)]
    print("Calculated,This is the FX:",FX)
    print("\n")
    SumFX=sum(FX)
    print("Sum of elements in FX is :",SumFX)
    print("\n")

    print("Final Output")
    Mean=SumFX/SumFrequencyNumber
    print("Mean is:",Mean)
```

the point were the problem occurs:

```
    def most_common(b):
        return(mode(b))
    ModeList=[[item for item, count in zip(ScoresNumber,FrequencyNumber) for i in range(count)]]
    b=(ModeList)
    print(most_common(b))

    ScoresNumber.sort()
    b=(ScoresNumber[-1])
    c=(ScoresNumber[0])
    Range=b-c
    print("Range is:",Range)
```

The whole program:

```
    import threading
    import statistics
    from statistics import mode
    import numpy as np
    print("Instructions:Enter a number than press ENTER until when fully completed")
    ScoresNumber=[]
    n = int(input("Entering amount of scores you want : "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
      
        ScoresNumber.append(ele) 
          
    print("These are the scores for the Frequency table",ScoresNumber)
    print("\n")

    print("Now enter Frequency")
    FrequencyNumber=[]
    a = int(input("Entering amount of frequencies you want : "))
    for i in range(0, a):
        ele = int(input())
      
        FrequencyNumber.append(ele)
    print("These are the frequencies for the Frequency table",FrequencyNumber)
    SumFrequencyNumber=sum(FrequencyNumber)
    print("Sum of elements in frequency is :",SumFrequencyNumber)
    print("\n")

    print ("Now calculating FX wait....")
    FX=[a * b for a, b in zip(FrequencyNumber,ScoresNumber)]
    print("Calculated,This is the FX:",FX)
    print("\n")
    SumFX=sum(FX)
    print("Sum of elements in FX is :",SumFX)
    print("\n")

    print("Final Output")
    Mean=SumFX/SumFrequencyNumber
    print("Mean is:",Mean)

    def most_common(b):
        return(mode(b))
    ModeList=[[item for item, count in zip(ScoresNumber,FrequencyNumber) for i in range(count)]]
    b=(ModeList)
    print(most_common(b))

    ScoresNumber.sort()
    b=(ScoresNumber[-1])
    c=(ScoresNumber[0])
    Range=b-c
    print("Range is:",Range)
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` I know that I can't be able to zip two lists together and compare each element but I'm trying to solve the problem.  I'm wondering if I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback?

Comment: Why is `ModeList` a list of lists instead of just a list?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
This code is not minimal.  Also, it hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: unhashable type: <whatever>` usually happens when you try to use something unhashable as a key in a hash indexed data structure (e.g. `dict`, `set`).

Looking at where you might be using list as a hash table index, the only part that might do it is using `mode`. Calculating frequencies is often done with a hash table. Let's test it.

```
In [1]: from statistics import mode

In [2]: mode([1,1,2])
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: mode([[1,1,2]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-23d99259e845> in <module>
----> 1 mode([[1,1,2]])

/usr/lib/python3.8/statistics.py in mode(data)
    556     """
    557     data = iter(data)
--> 558     pairs = Counter(data).most_common(1)
    559     try:
    560         return pairs[0][0]

/usr/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py in __init__(self, iterable, **kwds)
    550         '''
    551         super(Counter, self).__init__()
--> 552         self.update(iterable, **kwds)
    553
    554     def __missing__(self, key):

/usr/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py in update(self, iterable, **kwds)
    635                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
    636             else:
--> 637                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
    638         if kwds:
    639             self.update(kwds)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Yep, there we go... `mode` uses `collections.Counter` which is a `dict`.

So you just have to avoid using list of lists in `mode`. Not sure why you're doing that in the first place, but if you need to keep a nested iterable, you can replace the inner with `tuple` (note: you will not be able to modify the tuples afterwards). Alternatively, try to flatten your data to a single iterable.

Comment: Thank you , For helping me. - A random stranger on the internet

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, it would be nice if you could upvote/mark as best answer :)